# how to add sum of all the values in sql as a separate column

Tags: sql, domo

My table currently looks like this:

```
Partner    Date           Ad Unit   Revenue   
App        1/1/2020       x         10        
App        1/1/202        y         3
```

I need the additional column with sum of all revenue for the day so it looks like the following

```
Partner    Date           Ad Unit   Revenue   Total Revenue
App        1/1/2020       x         10        13
App        1/1/2020       y         3         13
App        1/2/2020       x         2         6
App        1/2/20202      y         4         6
```

I have tried the following code, but in the output it no longer breaks the data by Ad Unit, which is what I want...

```
SELECT
    `Date`,
    `Ad Unit`,
    `Partner`,
    `Revenue`,
    sum(`Revenue`) as `Total Revenue`
from
    `master_table`
group by
    `Date`
```

And the output now is

```
Partner    Date           Ad Unit   Revenue   Total Revenue
App        1/1/2020       x         10        13
```

How can I group the data so I have it broken down by Ad Unit and have a column for totals at the same time that is grouped by date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT mt.*, SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY date) as total_revenue
FROM `master_table` mt;
```

[This](https://knowledge.domo.com/Prepare/Magic_Transforms/ETL_DataFlows/03ETL_Actions%3A_Rank_and_Window) might help you understand them.

You can also do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT mt.*,
       (SELECT SUM(mt2.revenue) 
        FROM master_table mt2
        WHERE mt2.date = mt.date
       ) as total_revenue
FROM master_table mt;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it errored out with an error message: "Whoops! Something went wrong.", which is, of course, very helpful in debugging.